# How can set max height for height auto in CSS?

Tags: css

I want to set max height for div that set height auto like under code.

```
.background.left-sidebar {
  height: auto !important;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #999999;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 300px;
}

.left-sidebar {
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.left-sidebar-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #996699;
}

  <div class="right_block left-sidebar">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="top_block left-sidebar-top">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="marker">This</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I try to set `height:100%`, `height:auto`, but it doesn't work.

How can set max height for height auto in CSS?

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yoydR0?p=preview)

Comment: use `max-height`?

Comment: Try `height: 100vh`

Comment: yes absolutely correct @sebastianbrosch. max-height:200px; height:auto; will be set a max-height of the div

Comment: ...and solved your problem?

Comment: could you please avoid vh units. because it does not browser compatibility .check  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: I tried to use `height: 100vh`, but it doesn't works like this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yoydR0?p=preview).

Answer (score 5):

you can try :

```
height : 100vh;
```

to set your *div* as 100% of your viewport

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `max-height: 1000px !important;` together with `height: auto;` Have you tried that?

Comment: @egaoneko could you use height: 100% with max-height? You would need a parent div of course: https://jsfiddle.net/fL02zufu/ In that case your height would be "auto" in the sense that you would inherit it from your parent div but you'd have the max-height in place.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you'll even see this. You can use `height: auto;` which somehow does what you want. I think it takes all the content height and adds it to the parent height